# Java- How to draw a line on a JFrame

Tags: java, icons, imageicon

I am doing a homework where We use a image and put it into a imageIcon and put them into threads and have them race across the screen. The only problem is that I can't figure out how to draw a finish line on the JFrame object. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a BufferStrategy and getting the DrawGraphics and doing 
Graphics.DrawLine?

This will make it very simple for you but the only thing as you said you wanted it to race across the screen you would have to put it a while loop and keep changing the end of the line to make it have an illusion that it is moving.

Edit: Ah, I just read your question again. You do not have to create another while loop to make this appear just inject it into your while loop for the program so that it always render your finish line. Just make sure it renders your finish line first or else it will look silly when the icons are on top of it because then the line will be on top of them if it is not rendered first.

Comment: I see it doesn't have too many methods inside of it. How would I get it to draw a line?

Comment: g.drawLine(StartXCord, StartYCord, EndXCord, EndYCord);

Comment: Honestly me personally because I like messing with Int arrays and converting them to a buffered image that is how I would do it. Look up a guy on Youtube named TheChernoProject he is a great teacher and he even has this program where he will tutor you for a fee if you want to get into computer programming.

Comment: He was the reason why i got into computer programming.